# Trying to print all permutations using only 4 and 7 upto n digits using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm trying to print all permutations using only the digits 4 and 7 upto n digits using recursion like  (4,7,44,47,74,77) for 2 digits.I'm trying to call the function recursively twice. I can't figure what's wrong with my code.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> s;

void check(int a, int b)
{
    if(b==0)
    return;
    else
    {
        check(a*10+7, b--);
        s.push_back(a*10+7);
        check(a*10+4, b--);
        s.push_back(a*10+4);
    } 
    return;
}

int main(void)
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    check(0, t);
    for(auto i=s.begin();i!=s.end();i++)
    {
        cout<<*i<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_I can't figure what's wrong with my code._" Can you at least explain what _seems_ to be wrong with it? What happens when you run it? Why is that bad?

Comment: `b--` is certainly wrong. That will push the same `b` value into the next recursion (e.g `b` is reaped before the decrement).. Generally, don't decrement variables in recursive calls unless you absolutely have to. Opt for expressive arguments (`b-1`) instead. If you feel you *must* increment/decrement an auto variable, you *probably* was prefix, not postfix, operations.

Comment: I have no compilation errors but the vector s is empty after it runs. The code takes time to run so I've tried using a cout statement at the end but it doesn't execute. So im assuming the recursion happens but infinitely so it never reaches the next line.

Comment: @WhozCraig b-- was the problem but changing it to prefix didn't solve it. So I have used a regular statement before the function was called and it works. It would be great if you could explain why using decrement variables in recursive calls doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using post-decrement which has no effect on the recursive call. On the other hand, it has an unintended effect on the second call. Just decrement the `b` before both calls and only once.

Coupled with non-defensive `if(b==0)`, you get stack overflow when `b` slips into negative values and your program terminates.

Something a debugger or address sanitizer would immediately told you.